# Json Array of Objects saves only the last item

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework

I want to define an array of objects, then store objects within the array, however I only have one object in the array(last object), and I can't add more objects to it.

In Dataservice class

```
getData(){
 return this.storage.get('x').then((val) => {
  console.log('x',val);
 });
}

 async setData( Name, Code, date){
     let Info=[{
      Name:Name,
      Code:Code,
      date:date
      }];
      console.log(typeof(Info)); // returns object
    return this.storage.set('x',JSON.stringify(Info));
  }
```

Calling set and get methods in home page:

```
 async loadData() {
    await this.dataservice.getData();
  }
async addData(name,code,date){
    await this.dataservice.setData(name,code,date);
    this.getData()
    }
```

In Another function in home page:

```
postAPI(){
this.addData('Sara','XXX','2022/10/10');
}
```

Output:

```
    x [{…}]0: 
Name: "Sara"
Code: "XXX"
date: '2022/10/10'
[[Prototype]]: Object length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: You continue to set a new object in `setData`. You shuld retrive your data and add to them.

Comment: How to did that? When I'm using push, it returns an error (push is not a function)

Comment: You are setting an object with key `x`, but you are reading an object with key `"x"` (notice the extra quotes). If you use `JSON.stringify` on a string it will add quotes

Comment: @CristianTraìna I have edited the code can you please check it

Comment: Ok, now notice that `setData` is async and you are not awaiting it. So `getData` gets called before `setData` has finished

Comment: @CristianTraìna I have edited it but the same result

Comment: @jsN00b Yes I want to use the result, to see all the elements in the array, not only the last element added

Comment: After this line: `console.log(typeof(Info));`, try adding this: `const existingData = await this.storage.get('x'); Info = [...JSON.parse(existingData), ...Info];`

Comment: @jsN00b that's solved the problem can you please add it as answer to be able to accept it?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to remove an item from it? I have used splice but not working (async removeItem(index){
    const storedData= await this.storage.get('x');
    storedData.splice(index,1);
    return this.storage.set('x',storedData);
  })

Comment: Please try: `const storedData= await this.storage.get('x'); const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData); parsedData.splice(index,1); return this.storage.set('x',parsedData);`in the `removeItem` method. Will add an answer as well. :-)

Comment: @jsN00b please help me my array becomes like this ["[","\"","[","\"",",","\"","[","\" until the end of the array

Comment: This happens when one tries to use `...someVariable` where `someVariable` is the result of `JSON.stringify(someOtherVariable);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all responses to be saved then while adding the data to storage, first get all existing data from storage, then add/append data to existing data and then save all data back to storage.

```
async setData(Name, Code, date) {
  let existingData = await this.storage.get('x');
  let newData = { Name:Name, Code: Code, date: date };

  if (!existingData) {
    existingData = [newData]
  } else {
    existingData.push(newData);
  }
  await this.storage.set('x', JSON.stringify(existingData));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append data to storage, you first have to get it and append to it.

```
async setData(data: any) {
    let _tmp = await this.storage.get('x') || [] ;
    _tmp.push(data);
    await this.storage.set('x', _tmp);
}
```